# Converting Windows 7 mbr boot disk to GPT boot disk

Tags: windows-7, conversion, mbr, gpt

I want to use my old laptop Win7 Pro that was installed with MBR partitioning. I wnat to use this on my new laptop that only support UEFI boot. I have tried various solutions I've found but they all end up with GPT formatting but the disk is not bootable. I am presuming this is because the various conversions to GPT format only work if the MBR disk is a data disk, hence don't include the boot information (which I assume is the EFI System Partition). All I get when I convert to GPT is the data portion of the disk.

I'm hoping somebody out there has done this and could help me out. I would like to see if I can get the old Win7 disk to boot on the laptop although I plan to add an M2 SSD on my laptop where I would do a fresh install of Win7 with just the OS on this disk and use the hard drive for user accounts only but want to check that Win7 will indeed boot on the new laptop - it has Win10 installed and I really don't like Win10 as I feel it is almost as bad as the short lived Windows Vista or Win8.

I have a lot of S/W installed on my Win7 disk and really don't want to have to go through the process of re-installing it.

Many thanks in advance,

George Nelson

Comment: https://www.diskpart.com/windows-7/how-to-install-windows-7-on-gpt-partition-style-3889.html

Comment: Partitions are a lot different. BIOS/MBR & UEFI/gpt Windows partitions, note system has totally different format  & meaning between BIOS & UEFI
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations & 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898504%28v=vs.85%29.aspx You need ESP & Windows wants MSR before first NTFS partition. See: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2462234&p=14041251#post14041251 You really should retire Windows 7 as not supported anymore.